# Is it possible to customize the text in a dropdown in powerapps?

Tags: powerapps

I have a collection that comes from Dynamics 365 that is just a list of dates in YYM format, I would like to format the dropdown to display something more meaningful for the user.

For example Dynamics will return 191 (an int), I would like to display January '19, for 196 I'd display June '19

I can't see where in the dropdown control there are options to format the displayed text

Answer (score 2):

I just tried to replicate your behavior in one of my Temporary Apps I created.

But I believe you need your data as Date format, then and then Powerapps knows in which format to change it.

In my Example below I have connected to Dynamics CRM, Account Entity and from Account I selected Created on date. Image  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDfqF.png) shows data from crm without formatting.
[image: Iamge1]

Now when I format data with below Expression it will give me results as expected [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilB9M.png).

```
ForAll(Accounts,Text('Created On',"[$-en-US]mmmm 'dd"))
```

[image: Image2]

[image: iMAGE3]

Comment: I've marked as a useful answer (as it's a very good answer) but doesn't resolve for me. My data is coming through as an int. As a workaround for now I'm putting a label next to the dropdown with the formatted text in that. Ideally I could format in the dropdown control though. Thanks for the answer though

Answer (score 1):

This is a scrubbed example of something I did against a SharePoint list, but should be similar to what you are trying to do. Put this in `Items`:

```
ForAll(Choices([@'Books'].'Publication Date'), Text(DateValue(Value), "dddd, mmmm d yyyy"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Text Function. Here you have a pretty good documentation -> https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/charles_sterling/2016/12/02/controlling-how-dates-are-displayed-in-a-powerapps-application/

Hope this helps you...

Comment: Thanks for the link, do you know how I would apply that function to a dropdown?